# Error with `listings` and `tabularray` used together

Tags: listings, tabularray

I'm in the process of replacing `tabular` and `array` environments with `tblr` in some of my documents. It's already done for dozens of them, with no problem. But I hit a bump with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={ll}}
\lstinline|a\,b| & $a\,b$\\
\lstinline|a\ b| & $a\ b$\\
\lstinline|a\quad b| & $a\quad b$
\end{tblr}
    
\end{document}
```

With TeX Live 2022 and LuaLaTeX, this table worked fine with a `tabular` environment. With `tblr`, it compiles correctly as long as the last line of the table is commented out. If it's not, I get the following error:

```
/Volumes/Inoue/titi/Desktop/essai.tex:11: Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
\quad 
l.11 \end
       {tblr}
```

It seems to choke on the `\quad` inside `\lstinline`, and I can't understand why. Is this a limitation on `tblr`? Or am I using it incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Could you post a question of the centering problem on this site? Then I will see whether or not it is a bug of `tabularray`. I am the author of this package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `verb` option if you want to use verbatim commands inside `tabularray` tables (see subsection 3.1.5 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={ll},verb}
\lstinline|a\,b| & $a\,b$\\
\lstinline|a\ b| & $a\ b$\\
\lstinline|a\quad b| & $a\quad b$
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The only disadvantage of `tabularray` is the code compiles longer and therefore I still use regular tabular for simple tables but I am really impressed with how great the package is. It seems the creator(s) thought about so many things if not all :)

Comment: this work fine wit `\verb!...!` but not with `\begin{verbatim}
    BETWEEN 1 AND 3
    AND lo_quantity < 25;
\end{verbatim}` or `\begin{lstlisting}
    BETWEEN 1 AND 3
    AND lo_quantity < 25;
\end{lstlisting}˛`