# tabularray and listings combability

Tags: listings, tabularray

The following MWE (borrowed from [@Celdor answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679251/table-too-long-for-one-page-and-column-content-not-vertically-aligned/679260#679260)}, where is used `tabular` table, works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=sql,
        keywordstyle=\color{black!30!blue}\bfseries,
        columns=flexible,
        }

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{w{l}{11cm}|c}
\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT SUM(lo_extendedprice*lo_discount) AS revenue
    FROM lineorder, dwdate
WHERE d_yearmonthnum = 199401
    AND lo_orderdate = d_datekey
    AND lo_discount BETWEEN 4
    AND 6 AND lo_quantity
    BETWEEN 26 AND 35;
\end{lstlisting} & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Meanwhile its transformation to use the `tblr` package, even with option `verb`, doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=sql,
        keywordstyle=\color{black!30!blue}\bfseries,
        columns=flexible,
        }

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[j,m] | c},
                      rowsep=3pt,
                      verb}
\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT SUM(lo_extendedprice*lo_discount) AS revenue
    FROM lineorder, dwdate
WHERE d_yearmonthnum = 199401
    AND lo_orderdate = d_datekey
    AND lo_discount BETWEEN 4
    AND 6 AND lo_quantity
    BETWEEN 26 AND 35;
\end{lstlisting} & 1 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Compiling above MWE throw the following warnings:

```
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 1.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.25     \end
             {tblr}
?
```

and not produce anything. Did I oversimplified the inserting of `lstlisting` code, or `tabularray` doesn't support this yet?

On this question you can look as following-up question to [Error with `listings` and `tabularray` used together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645222/error-with-listings-and-tabularray-used-together)

Comment: `tblr` env absorbs its content using `ltcmd/xparse` arg-type `+b` (check how `\NewTblrEnviron` and `tblr` are defined in [package source](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/blob/e5f340b1f8a60b7b24acdf02991cf0a29811426a/tabularray.sty#L2622-L2639)), thus all the newlines in a verbatim env are irreversibly converted to spaces.  I don't see any easy workaround/fix. See discussion https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/13.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, thanks for info. I will check this at my next spare time (late evening in my time zone).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, i check discussion on github. It seems that tabularray will not handle verbatim/listings soon :-). So, the suggestion of Paul Gaborit in his answer below seems to be the only way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround using `filecontents*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=sql,
  keywordstyle=\color{black!30!blue}\bfseries,
  columns=flexible,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}[force]{\jobname-sql.tex}
SELECT SUM(lo_extendedprice*lo_discount) AS revenue
    FROM lineorder, dwdate
WHERE d_yearmonthnum = 199401
    AND lo_orderdate = d_datekey
    AND lo_discount BETWEEN 4
    AND 6 AND lo_quantity
    BETWEEN 26 AND 35;
\end{filecontents*}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[j,m] | c},
    rowsep=3pt,
    verb}
  \lstinputlisting{\jobname-sql.tex} & 1 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but ... my real table have 13 rows each with different listings. This means I need to define 13 `filecontents*` . Huh, a bit annoying! Anyway, thank you very much (ab for few days only +1)

Comment: @Zarko You can use a counter to differentiate each external file.

Comment: I already use your solution in my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679251/table-too-long-for-one-page-and-column-content-not-vertically-aligned/679425#679425.  I differentiate files similarly as you suggest in comment. It works fine and code is not so cumbersome as I afraid in the first.  Thank you again!